# Excel - replace a formula cell with its result automatically

Tags: excel, replace, return-value, formula

I am trying to make a sheet to add to templates that I give to my students for homework assignments; some of them are cheating by sending each other the files and I would like to catch them.

I have made a formula cell that populates with the current OS and directory of the file. What I would like to do is have this become text after evaluation so that if another student opens the file it will not change (but the following cell will, and so on..) Here is the formula:

(Cell A1):
`=INFO("osversion")&INFO("directory")`

(Cell A2 and beyond):
 `=IF(A1=(INFO("osversion")&INFO("directory")),"",IF(LEN(A1)<2," ",INFO("osversion")&INFO("directory")))`

Do you know if there is any way to have a formula cell be replaced by its value after execution without using VBA? (If I use VBA it asks if you want to enable macros on startup which kind of gives the game away...)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: VBA would be required.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But even if you could, you can't stop them and the reason being. I can always open other students copy and update my copy?

Comment: The aim would be that if I open another student's file on my computer it will add my OS and directory after his/hers! Seems that VBA is required as @Gary'sStudent said but I was hoping some genius could have a nice workaround...

Comment: You didn't get the point that I was driving in. Consider this. `Student A` has `1.xlsx`. `Student B` has 2.xlsx. After student A finishes his/her assignment, he/she create a copy of `1.xlsx`. Let's call it `Copy.xlsx`. Now he/she gives `Copy.xlsx` to `Student B`. `Student B` opens `Copy.xlsx` and copies the answers into `2.xlsx`. Once finished. he/she deletes `Copy.xlsx` and gives you `2.xlsx`. So now tell me how will you know `Student B` cheated?

Comment: Oh sorry, I get your point now. I did think of this but my suspicions are that they are using the same files; either way it's a bit beside the point now as it seems I can't do it anyway without VBA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround: Use Track Changes. If you are using Excel 2010, for example:

1. Go to the `Review` tab and in the `Changes` group click `Share Workbook`.
2. Click the checkbox for `Allow changes by more than one user at the same time`.
3. In the `Review` tab, select `Track Changes|Highlight Changes`.
4. You may wish to select `All` for the `When` option and `Everyone` for the `Who` option.

You can then choose to highlight changes on screen and/or list changes in a new sheet.

If you do that before you make your final changes to the file, you can confirm that nobody has `Accepted Changes` between the last time you saw the file and the time it is returned to you by checking that your last change is shown correctly.

That will then let you see all the people who have edited the file since you last edited it, and what changes they have made.

(EDIT)

As @Siddharth Rout pointed out in another answer, one can use technological means to make cheating on assignments more difficult but a sufficiently resourceful student can always find a way to circumvent such measures.

This predicament can be resolved by distinguishing two cases:

(a) learning opportunities where students can choose to learn (do the assignment and get feedback on their approach - not a mark) or not choose to learn, and

(b) evaluation processes where one can measure how much they have learned (e.g. by getting the students together under one roof).

In case (a) students are not being evaluated and so have no motivation to "cheat". In case (b), they are being evaluated but have no opportunity to cheat.

Comment: As @Siddharth Rout points out, using Track Changes would not address the problem of one student copying and pasting answers from another student's spreadsheet into their own spreadsheet, although a careful examination of the times and dates on the changes could show (in that case) that they were all pasted in at the same time - creating some indication that the student did not develop the answers step by step.

Comment: Way to think out of the box. I've used it so often that I didn't think about using it for this.

Comment: `although a careful examination of the times and dates on the changes could show (in that case) that they were all pasted in at the same time` Umm, Not necessarily. Say I received the copy yesterday and I worked on my file today. there can be no way there can be a time match. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: That's true. I was thinking that if changes were pasted in all at once they would all have the same time stamp. Of course that wouldn't stop someone pasting in the changes over a period of time to make the time stamp for each change realistic, but then it would almost be easier to answer the questions themselves.

Comment: I appreciate the Track Changes suggestion and I will have a look at using it. Also the suggestions for bettering the methods are very helpful - unfortunately as a TA my influence is somewhat limited! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know if there is any way to have a formula cell be replaced by its value after execution **without using VBA**?

The answer to your question is "**No, it cannot be done**"

---

Even if you considered VBA as an option, it's futile as this is a classic example of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

No matter what you do, you cannot stop your students from cheating. Consider these few scenarios.

**Scenario 1**

Student A has `1.xlsx`. Student B has `2.xlsx`. After student A finishes his/her assignment, he/she create a copy of `1.xlsx`. Let's call it `Copy.xlsx`. Now Student A gives `Copy.xlsx` to Student B. Student B opens `Copy.xlsx` and copies the answers into `2.xlsx`. Once finished, Student B deletes `Copy.xlsx` and gives you `2.xlsx`. So now tell me how will you know Student B cheated?

**Scenario 2**

Student B calls Student A on mobile. They both have their copies opened. Student A gives all the answers on the phone. How will you know Student B cheated?

**Scenario 3**

Student A and Student B open files in two laptops next to each other and finish the assignment. How would you know who cheated whose assignment?

**Alternative?**

Get all the students under one roof and then get them fill it up in front of you. There is no other way you can even guess whether someone cheated unless someone is fool enough to mention other students name in his/her template or copied the answers verbatim.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'm a TA for the class so I have a somewhat limited influence on how the class is run but I will make suggestions to the professor.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put some text in a cell location that only you know about and make the text white. You could code your text for each student and lock only the contents of that one cell with a password.

That's what I would do...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the professor (I'm the TA) creates a single template file that all the students download so in this case it wouldn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can give each of them a different problem (maybe the same problem with different data). You will detect cheating of any kind by just looking at the results.

Programming or IT is not always the solution, even to programming or IT problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I can't really change the way the questions are presented as I'm only the TA - I'll definitely bear it in mind though if the time comes that I am setting them!